# Rails ActiveRecord query on existing collection

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, mysql2

Suppose I have a result from a query:

```
allCourses = Course.all
```

Then I also have another set:

```
myCourses = current_user.courses.all
```

How can I get a set of items that are in allCourses and NOT in myCourses?

Here are the models:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :student_enrollments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :courses, through: :student_enrollments
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base   
    has_many :student_enrollments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :students, through: :student_enrollments
end

class StudentEnrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :student
    belongs_to :course
end
```

I can always write raw SQL script to achieve the result, but I prefer to find a Rails way to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assume your fk is `user_id`.

```
ohterCourses = Course.where('user_id != ?', current_user.id)
```

Comment: or `Course.where.not(user_id, current_user.id)`

Comment: It's not that simple. I have a joiner model for this many-to-many relationship. Even if I removed records with that user_id, other user_ids might have the same courses.
I just updated the question with the model.